# How to draw on "Image" component - WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap

I need to take an image from `Image` component, 
draw rectangle on it,
and put it back to an `Image` component.

I know how to draw on Bitmap but I cant find any easy way to draw on this `BitmapImage` that I get from Image.Source.

Comment: "Image component" are you referring to `Image` `Control`?

Comment: yes, this thing from XAML

Comment: Take a look at [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/).